# How to get all C# microservices together in same Swagger page

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, ocelot

I'm developing a platform where I have 3 microservices and an API Gateway done in Ocelot. The problem is that I want to get all microservices in a Swagger page like :
[image]

I don't want implement Swagger endpoints:
[image]

Thanks in advance. I'm stuck in these issue by several days.

Comment: Have to ask, but why do you care?

Comment: Hi Rand, sorry, I did not express the problem well. I want to combine all microservices swagger.json into a single swagger.json. This way, I will get something like first image. 

In other words, first image is what I want and seconda image is what I have and I don't want.

Comment: The issue wasn’t that I didn’t understand your problem. I simply wouldn’t care. So, I asked why do you care? Why invest time into solving this? what would be the benefit?

Comment: Because the api-docs must be in only one page and this page is generated by redocly and redocly needs only one swagger.json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no 'built-in' functionality in .NET that allows you to merge OpenAPI documents. In this case, you need to use an external library that allows you to merge OpenAPI documents or write such functionality yourself. When using external libraries, you must consider that they may not meet your requirements regarding, for example, filtering endpoints or handling conflicts (e.g., a model with the same name appears in several documents you are merging).

.NET, on the other hand, provides a very simple and user-friendly API that allows for very convenient work with OpenAPI documents - everything you might need can be found in the NuGet packages -
`Microsoft.OpenApi`. These packages cover practically everything you might need, from reading documents in various formats to manipulating structures.

Essentially, the most basic merging process will involve combining several lists from the OpenAPI document:

- Paths
- Components (in most simple case it'll be just a Components.Schemas)

Applying your own logic will allow you to manage the 'output' document in any way you want - relatively simple. I recently tried to solve the problem of merging OpenAPI documents, but unfortunately, most of the projects either didn't meet my requirements or support for them had been abandoned years ago.

Comment: Thanks Posio. I have so much work to get it working.

Comment: You can use existing opensource libraries. But in my case I hit it's limit very fast. Anyway, if you need the most basic solution. Maybe it's worth to give it a try.